# php - iterate on classes defined in a folder

Tags: php, class

I would like to iterate on all the classes defined inside a specific folder. Is it possible?

As far as I understand I can't use `get_declared_classes` because it considers only classes that have already been used.

Comment: What do you want to do with the classes?  Just iterate?  And what?

Comment: Consider using a [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader. When you namespace your classes according to the directory scrutcure, it is easy to iterate over them using eg. [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.innamespace.php).

Comment: @PavelKoch so you just suggest to start from the base directories declared in the `composer.json` and iterate through all the subfolders and the files contained there, and for each file considering a class with the same name?

Comment: With the same namespace, but yes, that is pretty much what I am suggesting. Or you can do it once and cache some kind of classmap. What do you need it for anyway?

Comment: I need to find all the classes extending some class, for several classes. So I tought to scan make one loop through all my classes and for each one check if it is an instance of the classes I need

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it:

```
function getDirClasses($dir)
{
    // store already declared classes:
    $predeclaredClasses = get_declared_classes();

    // Load classes inside the given folder:
    $i = new FileSystemIterator($dir, FileSystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    foreach ($i as $f) {
        require_once $f->getPathname();
    }

    // Enjoy
    return array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $predeclaredClasses);
}

var_dump(getDirClasses(__DIR__ . '/src'));
```

if for any reason, you don't want to load the classes, and you just want to classes names inside the given folder, then use this function:

```
function getDirClassesUsingGrep($dir)
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $cmd = 'grep --no-filename -E "^\S*class +.+( *{)?$" ' . $dir . '/* | cut -d" " -f2';

        exec($cmd, $output);

        return $output;
    }

    return false;
}


var_dump(getDirClassesUsingGrep(__DIR__ . '/src'));
```

Comment: interesting solution! This works nicely as a script; what if I would like to obtain the same result with a method call from a class, where I don't know which classes have been already required?